# Sorting array of objects by properties (multi-level)

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

I have an array of objects that is like this:

```
var array = [
    {minutes: 45, hours: 4, meridiem: "PM"},
    {minutes: 00, hours: 8, meridiem: "AM"},
    {minutes: 45, hours: 8, meridiem: "AM"},
    {minutes: 30, hours: 3, meridiem: "PM"},
    {minutes: 15, hours: 11, meridiem: "AM"},
    {minutes: 00, hours: 1, meridiem: "PM"}
]
```

Essentially I need to sort by time, earliest first. So by AM/PM then by hours and then by minutes if hours and meridiem are equal.

Here is what I've tried

```
this.currentTours.sort(function(a,b) {
  if (a.meridiem != b.meridiem) {
    return 1
  }
  if ((a.dateR.meridiem == b.dateR.meridiem) && a.dateR.hours != 
  b.dateR.hours) {
    return 1
  }
  if (((a.dateR.meridiem == b.dateR.meridiem) && a.dateR.hours != 
  b.dateR.hours) && a.dateR.minutes != b.dateR.minutes) {
    return 1
  }
  return a.dateR.meridiem - b.dateR.meridiem
})
```

Getting past 1 layer of properties is where I get stuck.

Comment: why not use a 24 hour system?

Comment: Show us what you already tried so we can help you to handle it. This is not a site where people do your work for you.

Comment: I know @voloshin thank you.

Comment: I think this -- How do you sort an array of objects based on multiple properties -- is a really good question, but it's unfortunate that _time_ is the example in use. It begs the question, as Nina says, why not just a 24 hour integer? `{minutes: 45, hours: 4, meridiem: "PM"}` is 1645 while `{minutes: 17, hours: 9, meridiem: "AM"}` is 945. Sorting that is trivial. An example with, say, `{name:"Fred", age:27, country:"GBR"}` where you want to sort by Country, then Age, then Name doesn't raise "Why don't you just X?" questions.

Comment: I think using a 24hr system is a good recommendation. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use a chained approach for a nested sorting, with a hour correction for [12 am or pm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/12-hour_clock). These values are interpreted as zero.

```
(a.hours < 12) * a.hours
```

```js
var array = [{ minutes: 45, hours: 4, meridiem: "PM" }, { minutes: 00, hours: 8, meridiem: "AM" }, { minutes: 45, hours: 8, meridiem: "AM" }, { minutes: 30, hours: 3, meridiem: "PM" }, { minutes: 15, hours: 11, meridiem: "AM" }, { minutes: 00, hours: 1, meridiem: "PM" }, { minutes: 00, hours: 12, meridiem: "PM" },{ minutes: 00, hours: 12, meridiem: "AM" }];

array.sort(function (a, b) {
    return (b.meridiem === 'AM') - (a.meridiem === 'AM')
        || (a.hours < 12) * a.hours - (b.hours < 12) * b.hours
        || a.minutes - b.minutes;
});

console.log(array);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use simple `if` statements in the `Array.prototype.sort` method to take multiple properties into account.

If two properties are exactly equal, consult the next most substantial property to break such ties.

```js
var array = [
  { minutes: 45, hours: 4, meridiem: "PM" },
  { minutes: 00, hours: 8, meridiem: "AM" },
  { minutes: 45, hours: 8, meridiem: "AM" },
  { minutes: 30, hours: 3, meridiem: "PM" },
  { minutes: 15, hours: 11, meridiem: "AM" },
  { minutes: 00, hours: 1, meridiem: "PM" }
];

array.sort(function(a, b) {
  if (a.meridiem !== b.meridiem)
    return a.meridiem === 'AM' ? -1 : 1;
  
  if (a.hours !== b.hours)
    return a.hours - b.hours;
  
  return a.minutes - b.minutes
});

console.log(array);
```